# What is wrong with my Cost per oz Calculations

Tags: c, math, casting

```
int main(){

    int TIMES_TAKEN_JUICE, COUNTER =0, amount_of_Juice, TOTAL_JUICE_TAKEN;
    float COST_OF_JUICE_TAKEN, JUICE_AMOUNT_TAKEN, COST_OF_JUICE, JUICE_COST_PER_OZ;

    printf("What is the weight (in oz.) of the original container of OJ?\n");
    scanf("%d", &amount_of_Juice);

    printf("What is the cost of the original container of OJ in dollars?\n");
    scanf("%f", &COST_OF_JUICE);

    JUICE_COST_PER_OZ = COST_OF_JUICE / (float) amount_of_Juice; 
    printf("%f", &JUICE_COST_PER_OZ);

    printf("How many times did your roommate take your juice?\n");
    scanf("%d", &TIMES_TAKEN_JUICE);

    while(COUNTER < TIMES_TAKEN_JUICE){

        printf("How much juice did your roommate take this time (in oz.)?\n");
        scanf("%d", &JUICE_AMOUNT_TAKEN);
        COUNTER++;
        TOTAL_JUICE_TAKEN += JUICE_AMOUNT_TAKEN;
        COST_OF_JUICE_TAKEN = TOTAL_JUICE_TAKEN * JUICE_COST_PER_OZ;

        if (COST_OF_JUICE_TAKEN >= 10.00)
        {
            printf("Your roommate owes you $10.00\n");
        }
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have no clue why the JUICE_COST_PER_OZ variable is not working. I have tried every possible combination I can think of.

Comment: "Not working" in what way? Does it throw errors? Is the value wrong? If so, what are your inputs, what value you see and what did you expect?

Comment: When I run it, The output is 0.000000000 every time. The value is supposed to be a hundredth place decimal.

Comment: _Side note:_ For idiomatic style, all uppercase variable names are generally used for constants (e.g. `#define PI 3.14159`). So, `JUICE_COST_PER_OZ` --> `juice_cost_per_oz`. And, since you're using "snake case" [which I prefer] as in `amount_of_Juice` vs "camel case" as in `amountOfJuice`, it helps to do all lowercase as in `amount_of_juice`

Comment: It does not output the correct cost of juice taken

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: I am having trouble with a running total using the TOTAL_JUICE_TAKEN variable. Every time I input a number for JUICE_AMOUNT_TAKEN, the total is not continually added. The Variable TOTAL_JUICE_TAKEN just spits out 0.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` needs `&` before variable names because it modifies them. `printf` doesn't because it only reads them. Make the printout read:

```
printf("%f", JUICE_COST_PER_OZ);
```

Style comment: I recommend you lowercase all the variables. Uppercase is normally only used for constants, not for regular variables.

Comment: There is only one issue left. The cost of juice taken when multiplied does not giveme the expected output

Comment: TOTAL_JUICE_TAKEN is not initialized

Comment: It is as an integer.

Comment: It is defined, but it is not initialized so its initial value in undefined (random value off the stack).  You need to set it to 0 before adding values to it.

Comment: I have fixed that, but it is still not outputting the correct cost of juice.